# how to get value of two normal button in a single form?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a form in which i have two input button one for multiple delete and another for multiple suspend items. like this-

```
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check_item[]" value="<?php echo $users['user_id']; ?>" />  
    <input type="button" id="suspendall" name="suspendall" value="Suspend" />
    <input type="button" id="deleteall" name="deleteall" value="Delete" /></td>

</form>
```

when I click on delete or suspend it ask for confirm that event by jquery like-

```
 $('#deleteall').click(function() {
    if(confirm('Really Want To Delete This?')){
        $('#listing').submit();
    }
 });
```

if it confirm cancel form is not submitted and if it confirm OK form is submitted and on submission i have to delete or suspend that item from db. I have write this code for this-

```
 if(isset($_POST['deleteall'])){           
       $check_array = $_POST['check_item'];
       $usersId =  implode($check_array,',');
       $db->deleteUser($usersId);
 }

 if(!empty($_POST['suspend'])){
       $check_array = $_POST['check_item'];
       $usersId =  implode($check_array,',');
       $db->suspendUser($usersId);
 }
```

the problem I am facing is both times when the form is submited i got only array of ids of check boxes. I am not able to identify which button is clicked because I am not getting button value. that why its not working, and if I changed these button into submit button its working very nice but didn't ask for confirm the event. What should I do for that. Do anyone have any solution for that, Please help me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

In you HTML form has a hidden form field.

On the JS event set the value of the hidden field before submitting

```
$('#deleteall').click(function() {
if(confirm('Really Want To Delete This?'))
{
    $("#hiddenFormId").val("deleteAll");
    $('#listing').submit();
}
});
```

Then use this type of code in your PHP (Sorry not a PHP programmer)

```
if $_POST['hiddenFormId'] == 'deleteAll'
```

Comment: and how to take this id on my php page for delete or suspend.?

Comment: Sorry I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: if I take hidden fields and store their value in a variable, how it will work and how I identify this on my php page where I have written query, which button is clicked?

Comment: The hidden field will be accessible as normal POST'd form data

Answer (score 0):

When submitting with jQuery().submit() the button on which was clicked is lost. 
You could try to not submit() the form in the click handler but instead call evt.preventDefault() when ! confirmed().

Comment: didn't get you, how it work and how I identify this on my php page which button is clicked?